# What is a good site to use for finding physical constants at times when NIST web resources are affected by government shutdowns?

Tags: resource-recommendations, physical-constants

There are multiple resources for finding physical constants (say, particle data, [atomic spectra](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database), or even [special-function identities](http://dlmf.nist.gov/)) which are generally hosted by  [NIST](https://www.nist.gov), and which form essential parts of the scientific infrastructure of multiple fields.

However, on occasion, these essential NIST-hosted websites can become unavailable for extended periods of time, particularly when NIST's funding is affected by government shutdowns in the US.

What are suitable alternatives which can be used in this situation?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the physical constants you may be looking for?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question. The [site guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/how-should-we-handle-how-to-find-a-specific-reference-requests) are explicitly OK with questions that ask how to find resources which are otherwise hard to find.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty That's true, although I don't think this falls in that category. The meta question you linked was about [tag:specific-reference] questions, where the question asks for a known paper/book/etc. which can be identified uniquely e.g. by title or DOI. This case is different since it's not asking for a specific document. In this case, I'd rather see one general question asking for resources for physical constants, period. Presumably one answer would recommend NIST, but when NIST is unavailable, you just move on to the next answer.

Comment: @DavidZ I see quite clear parallels, but they're mostly moot. Frankly, I think the general phrasing you propose would significantly decrease this answer's usefulness to external searches, given how central the NIST resources are and how large of a population is looking for alternatives when they're down. Your proposal would render it invisible (or much harder to find) to that population.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty In that case, I'd want to see this marked as a duplicate of that general question, or phrased in a way that the same keywords appear. We get the best of both worlds that way. Anyway, I'm not particularly invested in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov) is the only way to go.

Comment: Great resource.  (1) Does it have data other than particle?