# Are there accepted spectral lines, or wavelength of light emitted, for the various neural and ionized atoms? If yes, where can I find them?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, atoms, wavelength

I am working with the redshift phenomena and analyzing the spectral lines of various emissions by galaxies. However, when I came to analyze the change in wavelength I was confused on what to compare to in terms of rest emitted wavelength. I found various values for the same ionized atom that varied tremendously. I am wondering if there were accepted values for the wavelength emitted by the atoms?

Comment: have you checked NIST spectra database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My go-to resource is the [NIST Atomic Spectra Database](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectra-database).

Doubtless there are other resources for specific applications, in which case you'll have to ask the people who actually work on those applications.

A related question, [What are good, reliable databases of atomic spectra?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/455637/what-are-good-reliable-databases-of-atomic-spectra), asks for alternatives.